# How can I troubleshoot my website on a Smart TV browser?

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser, cross-browser

We bought a Samsung Smart TV to mount on the wall and display our company dashboard.  I wrote the dashboard in HTML/Javascript/CSS and everything is going well.  It's to a point that I felt comfortable displaying it on the big screen.  However most of the data does not load.  I have no idea how to access a console of any type.  I've tried changing my agent string to match in Chrome dev tools, but of course that doesn't emulate capabilities.  I also downloaded the "2014 Smart TV Emulator 5.1" from Samsung's site and got it running in VirtualBox but as far as I can tell you can *only* use it to debug and emulate native Tizen apps.  I can't figure out how to launch the browser on the emulated set.

So, how can I troubleshoot my web app on a Smart TV Browser?

Comment: Look for Wienre

Comment: Interesting, but it looks like the client requires "recentish WebKit browsers".  Since I suspect that's my problem this might not help.  I'll give it a go though.

Comment: For anyone viewing this, do yourself a favor and buy a raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tizen SDK/ Tizen Studio you can debug Tizen web application:

Run As > Tizen Web Simulator Application (Samsung TV)

[image]

Click on Web Inspector.

[image]

You can see your console here.

[image]

Comment: It's literally just a web site so I don't think this applies.

Comment: Could you tell me how to receive console log from Samsung smart TV legacy device (non Tizen)?Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1788736 For Debugging (+ console log viewing) in Samsung Legacy TV Platform-> May Check this Guide http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/legacy-platform-library/d44/index